# GPS tracker with flutter?

Tags: flutter, gps

I want to make a GPS Tracker device and integrate it with flutter. But I have no experience and zero knowledge relating to that GPS staff. I don't know where to start or even if it is possible or not?

Anyone suggestion? What kind of GPS device that I can use, How to can I connect with flutter? via API? Which? Where to buy those devices(GPS)?

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Your question is too generic. How can we help you? In any case: https://docs.flutter.dev/resources/faq#what-kinds-of-apps-can-i-build-with-flutter so flutter ecosystem can do GPS. Now you should be more focused on the step you must do and eventually ask it

Comment: Okay, I got that thank you, I think it helps if someone guides me through GPS stuff from their experience working on a similar senario.

Comment: Hello, did you found something how to implement this ?